# Windows Dual Boot together with Ubuntu 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" - minimal - command line installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Tell me please is it possible to use Windows 10 in Dual Boot together with Ubuntu 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" 54MB minimal command-line installation with no login manager?

[Installation/LowMemorySystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems)
& [Installation/MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Is it right that from what I can understand from 
[WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) Ubuntu needs only GRUB2 to can boot together with Microsoft Windows, without any login manager.

Ubuntu 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" 54MB - minimal command line installation use and has GRUB2, correct?

I would like to specify that Ubuntu 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" 54MB, Windows will be installed afterwards.

Comment: I recommend Windows first; then Ubuntu. However, what you are describing is perfectly possible.