# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 “Xenial Xerus” - minimal - command line installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Windows 10 has already being installed before doing the following:

First I couldn't boot the new USB Stick created [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus"](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) from [Installation/MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

in UEFI mode like I've done with a few minutes ago, just for test with the Windows 10 USB Stick.

I had to boot it in Legacy mode, in order for the USB Stick of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" to run.

I installed [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus"](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) from [Installation/MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) - command line installation.

GRUB has been installed on ext4, dev/sdb2, sda was the USB Stick.

All done, now in UEFI starts only Windows 10 automatically, and in Legacy mode, no system to start at all.

Now, when I try to access from WIndows the partition where Ubuntu should, I can't access it, and it asks only for formatting it.

Do you consider that if I would do this with a full Lubuntu (not Ubuntu) installation would work?

Any ideas please?
Thank you.

Comment: Minimal does not have an UEFI install mode. If you want small use the server version but not install any software, or install desktop of choice. If you want BIOS boot on gpt drive, you have to have a 1 or 2MB bios_grub partition unformatted. And then install grub to MBR or sda, not to a partiiton like sdb2. Grub in UEFI mode only installs to the ESP on sda, If external you have to copy files from ESP on sda's ESP to external's ESP & copy again and rename shim to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.

Comment: Thank you very much @oldfred, tell me please if I will use "the server version but not install any software" I will still must do everything after  "If you want BIOS boot on gpt drive, you have to" in order to have a working dual boot please? Regards.

Comment: You have to first decide if you want UEFI or BIOS boot. Bit more complicated with UEFI on external. I have created full installs on flash drive both ways. Server version uses  tasksel to choose extra software packages to install. But you will be then at command line unless you also install gui or full desktop. UEFI Full install to external USB drive or flash drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338836 by Halbarad

Comment: Thank you @oldfred I would like to install on HDD as minimal as possible https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems like in here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/845475/windows-dual-boot-together-with-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-minimal-command. I would like only the kernel to boot in tty, and only use fvwm, no login manager, no other environment at all if it is possible.  I don't know if in Legacy mode will find the HDD at all(from my trying until now in Legacy only the USB could start). With respect.

Comment: If Windows 10, you must turn off its fast start up or always on hibernation. Otherwise the Linux NTFS driver cannot see it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Tell me please @oldfred is it ok to follow this guide? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI And tell me please it will be any problem that Linux will install again on sdb2, and Windows will be on sdb ? Because I think sda will stil be the USB.

Comment: If flash drive is sda, then that is a problem, as then grub will overwrite the boot loader on the flash drive.

Comment: Even if I will chose the grub to be written on sda2? Is there any way to chose the HDD to be recognized as sda?

Comment: You never write grub to a partition, only to a drive. But with UEFI installs, I yet to have grub install to any place other than sda's ESP, overwriting my default Ubuntu boot in that ESP. I have tried installing to my HDD, as sdb and to flash drives as sdc all with thier own ESP available. I end up copying files from sda to other drive and restoring ESP on sda.